# Need help embedding j2mod library into a java plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, dependencies

I need some help using [j2mod](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ghgande/j2mod), a java library for Modbus TCP/RTU into a plugin for Universal Robots.

Using the maven-bungle-plugin.

What I have tried:

- Including dependencies one by one (never ending dependency tree)
- Using the `<Export-Package>` tag to include the j2mod package in jar (program starts with a requires 'jSerialComm' error)
- Using `<Embed-Dependency>` tag to include all dependencies of scope compile and runtime (program starts with a requires 'org.slf4.impl' error and I cant seem to figure out a way to adapt slf4j to log4j).

I know from snooping around the polyscope simulator program's files. The simulator seems to use `log4j-api-2.3.jar` and a `modified-log4j-core-1.11.6.jar`.

Any insights on using j2mod or a similar java Modbus TCP/RTU library in an embedded system environment will me helpful.

Comment: Not sure what a "plugin" is in this case, but what about using maven-shade?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.